# How do I check if an iOS subscription is active?

Tags: unity, ios, in-app-purchase

How do I check if an iOS subscription is active?  Subscriptions are the only type of purchase available; however, there are several subscription lengths.  I have scoured the internet, but all I can find is receipt verification.

The following code seems to work for Android:

```
var products = storeController.products.all;
bool subscribed = products.Where(p => p.hasReceipt).Count() > 0;
```

(although I am not sure if it takes the subscription's expiration date into account.)

But this does not work for iOS.  How can I check to see if they have a valid iOS subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Unity now has a built in `SubscriptionManager`.  You can use it to determine Subscription validity.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPSubscriptionProducts.html